# Must I pay rent to be considered a Lodger in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, rent, tenant

This question is inspired by [How to prove you live somewhere when you live at some friend house for the National Insurance Number in UK](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/121980/9549) and [How to prove you live somewhere when you live at some friend house for the National Insurance Number in UK](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/15033/16166) at the Workplace and Expats.

Is it required to pay rent to be considered a Lodger in the UK? For example, can I get a lodger agreement without any rent, or something like £1?

This section at [citizensadvice.org.uk](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/housing/renting-a-home/subletting-and-lodging/lodging/lodging/) suggest that rent is optional, but it's not entirely clear:

> Lodgers generally pay a charge that covers rent and bills and in some cases other services, such as cleaning, may be provided too.